# What does .yaml do to my column in the below syntax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, I am trying to add a column that holds an array of strings,to one my tables like so:

```
`add_column :videos, :thumbnails, :string, array: true, default: []`
```

But the above throws an error: `TypeError: can't quote Array`.

I've been researching ways to fix this issue and I came across this:

```
add_column :videos, :thumbnails, :string, array: true, default: [].to_yaml`
```

What does .yaml do to my column? And is there another way to go about this? By the way, I am using Rails 5.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: Are you sure you're running that migration with PostgreSQL? It should work without the `to_yaml` and it does work for me.

Comment: Yes I am running it with postgresql. I also tried making default as "{}" and have tried it without a default value.

Comment: And you're sure that that `add_column` call is triggering the `TypeError`? As I said earlier, it looks fine and it works for me so something odd is going on.

Comment: Just curious: since you're using PG why not just use a column type suited for the data you're saving? I mean why not just use a `:json` type column.
I think @Amit answered your question though.

Comment: @oreoluwa he is using a native array column with the varchar data type. I would say that that is just as valid of a choice as JSON.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to serialize a ruby object(`Array`) to database string column.

To make that possible you need to call `to_yaml` which convert array into yaml `String` format. There is no other way but you have to do that.

`1] pry(main)> ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQU1tFkpMag', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYa_Z2pYzcU'].to_yaml
=> "---\n- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQU1tFkpMag\n- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYa_Z2pYzcU\n"
2] pry(main)> [].to_yaml
=> "--- []\n"`

When you read that column, it will be deserialize to ruby object and you well get ruby array.

Worth reading https://www.viget.com/articles/how-i-used-activerecord-serialize-with-a-custom-data-type/

Comment: This is not correct for actual native postgres array columns which is what the migration creates. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array